# I'm getting the error " SQL Error: ORA-01427

Tags: sql

for the below SQL-script I'm getting the following error:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
SELECT (a.student_id) AS StudentId,
          'P19' AS UniversityId,
          SUBSTR (a.degree_code, 1) AS TargetScientificDegreeId,
          SUBSTR (a.degree_code, 1) AS GrantedScientificDegreeId,
          DECODE (admission_major_no,
                  1, 'H01',
                  2, 'J01',
                  3, 'F05',
                  4, 'F05',
                  5, 'F05',
                  6, 'F05',
                  7, 'F05')
             AS AdmissionCollegeId,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (code, 1, 3)
             FROM hi_faculties_map h
            WHERE H.FACULTY_NO = a.faculty_no)
             AS CurrentCollegeId,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (code, 1, 4)
             FROM sis_majors q,
                  sis_student_majors z,
                  sis_depts r,
                  hi_depts_map h
            WHERE     q.major_no = z.major_no
                  AND z.is_active = 1
                  AND q.faculty_no = r.faculty_no
                  AND q.dept_no = r.dept_no
                  AND r.dept_no = h.dept_no
                  AND r.faculty_no = h.faculty_no
                  AND z.student_id = a.student_id)
             UniversityDepartmentId,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (code, 1, 4)
             FROM hi_majors_map w, sis_student_majors h
            WHERE     is_active = 1
                  AND H.STUDENT_ID = a.student_id
                  AND W.MAJOR_NO = H.MAJOR_NO)
             AS UniversityMajorId,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (code, 1, 4)
             FROM hi_majors_map w, sis_student_majors h
            WHERE     is_active = 1
                  AND H.STUDENT_ID = a.student_id
                  AND W.MAJOR_NO = H.MAJOR_NO)
             UniversityMinorId,
          (SELECT TO_NUMBER (MAX (level_no))
             FROM sis_study_levels x, sis_student_majors h
            WHERE     X.MAJOR_NO = h.MAJOR_NO
                  AND h.student_id = a.student_id
                  AND H.IS_ACTIVE = 1)
             StudyProgramPeriod,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (COUNT (semester_code), 1)
             FROM sis_study_semesters
            WHERE is_optional = 0)
             StudyProgramPeriodUnitId,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (MAX (to_hour), 1, 3)
             FROM sis_study_levels x, sis_student_majors h
            WHERE     X.MAJOR_NO = h.MAJOR_NO
                  AND h.student_id = a.student_id
                  AND H.IS_ACTIVE = 1)
             RequestedCreditHoursCount,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (attempted_hrs, 1, 2)
             FROM sis_academic_records q
            WHERE     Q.STUDENT_ID = a.student_id
                  AND q.semester IN (SELECT semester
                                       FROM sis_degree_calendar y
                                      WHERE     Y.IS_CLOSED = 0
                                            AND Y.IS_ACTIVATED = 1))
             RegisteredCreditHoursCount,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (SUM (x.crd_hrs), 1, 3)
             FROM sis_student_courses z, sis_courses x
            WHERE     x.course_no = z.course_no
                  AND z.is_passed = 1
                  AND z.student_id = a.student_id)
             PassedCreditHoursCount,
          (SELECT NVL (sis_graduation_pkg.get_remain_hrs (student_id,
                                                          faculty_no,
                                                          MAJOR_NO,
                                                          NULL,
                                                          NULL,
                                                          NULL,
                                                          0),
                       0)
             FROM SIS_ACADEMIC_RECORDS Q
            WHERE     Q.STUDENT_ID = a.student_id
                  AND Q.SEMESTER = (SELECT MAX (Q.SEMESTER)
                                      FROM SIS_ACADEMIC_RECORDS Q
                                     WHERE Q.STUDENT_ID = a.STUDENT_ID))
             RemainingCreditHoursCount,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (code, 1)
             FROM hi_student_status_map h
            WHERE H.status_code = a.status_code)
             AS AcademicStatusId,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (code, 1)
             FROM hi_study_types_map h
            WHERE H.study_code = a.study_code)
             AS StudyTypeId,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (code, 1)
             FROM hi_rs_student_status_map h, sis_academic_records w
            WHERE     H.STATUS_CODE = W.STATUS_CODE
                  AND W.STUDENT_ID = a.student_id
                  AND w.SEMESTER = (SELECT MAX (w.SEMESTER)
                                      FROM sis_academic_records w
                                     WHERE w.student_id = a.student_id))
             RegistrationStatusId,
          (SELECT year
             FROM sis_academic_records z,
                  sis_study_levels y,
                  sis_student_majors q
            WHERE     Z.MAJOR_NO = Y.MAJOR_NO
                  AND z.level_no = Y.LEVEL_NO
                  AND Z.STUDENT_ID = a.student_id
                  AND q.student_id = a.student_id
                  AND Q.IS_ACTIVE = 1
                  AND Q.MAJOR_NO = Y.MAJOR_NO
                  AND Z.STUDENT_ID = Q.STUDENT_ID
                  AND Z.MAJOR_NO = q.major_no
                  AND Z.PLAN_TYPE = Y.PLAN_TYPE
                  AND Q.PLAN_TYPE = Z.PLAN_TYPE
                  AND Q.PLAN_TYPE = Y.PLAN_TYPE
                  AND q.EDITION = Y.EDITION
                  AND z.SEMESTER = (SELECT MAX (z.SEMESTER)
                                      FROM sis_academic_records z
                                     WHERE z.student_id = a.student_id))
             CurrentAcademicYearId,
          gen_pkg.get_hijrah (a.join_date, 'yyyy') AdmissionHijriYear,
          TO_CHAR (a.join_date, 'yyyy') AdmissionGregorianYear,
          (SELECT TO_CHAR (start_date, 'yyyy')
             FROM sis_academic_calendar w
            WHERE     semester IN (SELECT semester
                                     FROM sis_degree_calendar
                                    WHERE is_activated = 1 AND is_closed = 0)
                  AND A.DEGREE_CODE = w.degree_code
                  AND item_code = 3)
             AS CurrentYear,
          MOD (join_semester, 10) AttendenceSemesterTypeId,
          (SELECT MOD (semester, 10)
             FROM sis_degree_calendar
            WHERE is_activated = 1 AND is_closed = 0)
             CurrentSemesterTypeId,
          sis_reg_pkg.get_student_level (
             a.student_id,
             sis_reg_pkg.add_semester (a.student_id, 0, -1))
             CurrentLevel,
          (SELECT grading_type
             FROM SIS_GRADING_SYSTEMS
            WHERE system_code = 1)
             GPATypeId,
          sis_reg_pkg.get_student_gpa (a.student_id, NULL, 1) GPA,
          (SELECT code
             FROM hi_evaluations_map l,
                  sis_academic_records y,
                  sis_gpa_grading c
            WHERE     L.EVALUATION_CODE = c.EVALUATION_CODE
                  AND y.semester IN (SELECT semester
                                       FROM sis_degree_calendar z
                                      WHERE     Z.IS_ACTIVATED = 1
                                            AND Z.IS_CLOSED = 0)
                  AND y.student_id = a.student_id
                  AND cum_gpa BETWEEN c.MIN_GPA AND c.MAX_GPA)
             CurrentSemesterAssessmentId,
          (SELECT '="' || SUBSTR (CODE, 1, 7) || '"' CODE
             FROM HI_CAMPUSES_MAP J
            WHERE J.CAMPUS_NO = A.CAMPUS_NO)
             StudyLocationCityId,
          (SELECT DECODE (Q.STUDY_CODE, 1, '0')
             FROM sis_academic_records q
            WHERE     Q.STUDENT_ID = a.student_id
                  AND q.semester IN (SELECT semester
                                       FROM sis_degree_calendar y
                                      WHERE     Y.IS_CLOSED = 0
                                            AND Y.IS_ACTIVATED = 1))
             AS WarningCount,
          (SELECT code
             FROM hi_evaluations_map l, sis_gpa_grading c
            WHERE     L.EVALUATION_CODE = c.EVALUATION_CODE
                  AND sis_reg_pkg.get_student_gpa (a.student_id, NULL, 1) BETWEEN c.MIN_GPA
                                                                              AND c.MAX_GPA)
             AccumulatedAssessmentId,
          DECODE (A.REWARD_TYPE, 0, 'null')
             AS IsRewardReceivedForCurSemester,
          (SELECT h.code
             FROM hi_countries_map h, sis_campuses r
            WHERE H.COUNTRY_NO = R.COUNTRY_NO AND r.campus_no = a.campus_no)
             CountryId,
          (SELECT TO_CHAR ( (entry_date), 'yyyy')
             FROM sis_semester_trans z
            WHERE     z.trans_code = 7
                  AND z.student_id = a.student_id
                  AND Z.TRANS_CODE = A.STATUS_CODE)
             AS GradutionYear,
          (SELECT TO_CHAR (entry_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
             FROM sis_semester_trans z
            WHERE     z.trans_code = 7
                  AND z.student_id = a.student_id
                  AND Z.TRANS_CODE = A.STATUS_CODE)
             AS GraduationDate,
          (SELECT DECODE (status_code,  1, '1',  2, '1')
             FROM sis_academic_records
            WHERE     attempted_hrs > 0
                  AND semester LIKE '%%3'
                  AND semester IN (SELECT semester
                                     FROM sis_degree_calendar
                                    WHERE is_activated = 1 AND is_closed = 0))
             AS SummerSemesterRegistratiStatus,
          (SELECT CASE
                     WHEN A.TRANSFER_UNIVERSITY IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
                     ELSE '2'
                  END
             FROM sis_students z
            WHERE z.student_id = a.student_id)
             AS IsTransfered,
          DECODE (A.BUILDING_CODE, NULL, 'null')
             AS IsAccommodationInUniversity,
          DECODE (A.ADMISSION_MAJOR_NO, NULL, 'null') AS IsMajorEducational,
          (SELECT SUBSTR (
                     DECODE (major_no,
                             1, 3,
                             2, 3,
                             3, 3,
                             4, 3,
                             5, 2,
                             6, 2,
                             7, 3),
                     1)
             FROM sis_student_majors x
            WHERE x.student_id = a.student_id AND X.IS_ACTIVE = 1)
             AS MajorTypeId,
          TO_CHAR (join_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') AS AcceptenceDate,
          (SELECT TO_CHAR (entry_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
             FROM sis_semester_trans z
            WHERE     z.trans_code IN (7, 6)
                  AND z.student_id = a.student_id
                  AND Z.TRANS_CODE = A.STATUS_CODE
                  AND z.SEMESTER = (SELECT MAX (w.SEMESTER)
                                      FROM sis_academic_records w
                                     WHERE w.student_id = a.student_id))
             AS DisclaimerDate,
          DECODE (A.SOCIAL_SECURITY, NULL, ' null')
             AS disclaimerDecisionBarginNunber,
          TO_CHAR (a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
             AS DateOfLastUpdateOnAcadmStatus
     FROM sis_students a
    WHERE     a.study_code = 1
          AND a.student_id = (SELECT MAX (student_id)
                                FROM sis_students x
                               WHERE X.NATIONAL_ID = A.NATIONAL_ID)
```

Comment: Please format the sql as per stack overflow standards. You have many sub queries there. You have to debug it one by one to check which sub query returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, this error says that one of your subqueries has more than one returned row:

```
select (select something from somewhere where something = somecondition) as derived_column
from mytable
```

The subquery has more than 1 row returned. You will need to debug them all.